# I'm having issues using APIs in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So i'm having an issue defining the price using the coinbase API for node.js, I'm able to send the embed alright, but I'm a bit used what I'm missing in order to display the price.  Thanks in advance!

```
exports.run = async (client, msg, args) => {
const Discord = require('discord.js');

var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
  var client = new Client({'apiKey': 'API KEY',
                         'apiSecret': 'API SECRET'});

client.getBuyPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, price) {
  const av = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("BTC Price Checker")
    .setDescription(price)
    .setFooter("Created with ❤️ by anonymous");
  msg.channel.send(embed)
  msg.delete();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is a discord.js problem might have more luck going to the coinbase-api section of stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coinbase-api?tab=Newest)

However a couple things you can try to get your problem,

1: checking that you have api_key and api_secret set to your key & secret

```js
var Client = require('coinbase').Client;
  var client = new Client({'apiKey': 'API KEY', // here
                         'apiSecret': 'API SECRET'}); // and here
```

2: checking for errors

```js
client.getBuyPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, price) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

3: checking what the variable "price" is before sending it (console.log)

```js
client.getBuyPrice({'currencyPair': 'BTC-USD'}, function(err, price) {
    console.log(price)
});
```

---

On a side note some other things i've noticed.

1: you have client set in the parameters of exports.run, you also define it later on. This is bad practice and can lead to some errors later on.

```js
var Client = require("coinbase").Client;

exports.run = async (bot) => {
   var client = new Client({'apiKey': 'API KEY','apiSecret': 'API SECRET'});
}
```

2: you define av but you never use it anywhere? (line 9)

3: you delete the message directly after sending it, might be your problem?  (line 15)

---

Overall your problems are not with discord.js but rather lie within the request to coingbase / the way you've coded it, try having a look at the documentation for coinbase-api [here](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node)